# Powershell Error initializing default drive: 'a call to SSPI failed see inner exception

Tags: powershell, active-directory, remote-server

I have been using some powershell scripts to query active directory users and its very useful

Recently the script stops working even though I have not changed it !

I don't understand why.   The prereqs etc. have not been altered

The errors im getting include:

"import-module: a local error has occurred ....   { import-module $_  }...

Error initializing default drive:  'a call to SSPI failed see inner exception...

I am using windows 8 64 bit  had all the pre reqs sorted e.g.  RSAT tools, powershell option enabled.   Dot net 4.5 etc. have enabled RSAT through add remove programs.

I have tested the same script on another windows 7 machine and it works fine which makes it look like there is something awry on the windows 8 machine.   I have googled about but haven't found a working solution.

Ive checked to see if id unchecked anything that would upset powershell but don't see anything.   Ive recreated my windows profile, I have reinstalled the RSAT tools for windows 8.1 64 bit. Ive re domained the machine.

The active directory scripts were running fine then suddenly stopped.   I haven't Installed any software recently.   I'm a domain admin and can use active directory with the gui with no problems. I'm at a loss.

Wondering if anyone knows what could have upset powershell on the windows 8 system or see anything ive overlooked

Thanks for reading

Confuseis

Comment: I have seen this when authenticating with a smartcard and smartcard is removed. Works again after reauthenticating to the domain.

Comment: No smart card on this occasion & I have re domained the machine.  Interestingly it will intermittently run the get-aduser sections of the script but no longer run the get-adprinciplegroupmembership  command !    - the term get-adPrinciplegroupmembership is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet....    why would powershell discriminate ?  its either loaded the active directory module or it has not & why would the script work for months and then suddenly spew errors?

Comment: Sorry, I have nothing further to add other than log off and back on and see if your problems persist.